# Close a PDF with python

Tags: python, pdf

The code that I'm writing has to rename and change the directory of some PDFs in a certain folder; both the new name and the new directory of a single PDF depend on the content of the PDF itself. The PDFs differ pretty much each other, so it is not trivial to extract the data that I need.

Said that, I decided to proceed in this way:

- Open and display the PDF;
- Search manually the parameters that I need in the opened PDF;
- Give the parameters found as inputs;
- Close the PDF;
- Rename the PDF with his new name and his new directory.

However I'm not manage to close the opened PDF, so I cannot rename it if it is opened. I wrote this code as an example:

```
import os

oldpath = "C:\\Users\Desktop\Training/"
os.chdir = oldpath

for oldname in os.listdir(oldpath):

    os.startfile(oldname)

    print("Parameter 1")
    P1 = input()
    print("Parameter 2")
    P2 = input()
    print("Parameter 3")
    P3 = input()

    #I want to close the opened file here

    newpath = oldpath + "/" + P1 + "/" + P2 + "/"
    newname = P3 + ".pdf"

    os.rename(oldpath + "/" + oldname, newpath + "/" + newname)
```

Could you suggest me how to solve this problem? Do you think there is a smarter way to do it?

Regards

Comment: If you just need to rename files, you don't need to open them. You may delete the line `os.startfile(oldname)` and that should do it.Besides, your code is not searching for the parameters in the file, it is just taking them as input.

Comment: Actually the new name is determined by some parameters written in the pdf, so I am forced to open it I think.

Comment: Q: Any luck with this?

Answer (score 2):

Using `os.startfile()` is a rather clever approach, and I'm surprised that it seems to allow you to read (at least *SOME*) of what you want to read from your .pdf's.  Cool!

But you cannot "close" the application (presumably Acrobat Reader, on Windows):

> https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html
>
> `startfile()` returns as soon as the associated application is launched.
>   There is no option to wait for the application to close, and no way to
>   retrieve the application’s exit status.

SUGGESTION:

Try using a .pdf library to "open" and "read" from your .pdf's instead.  For example, [PDFMiner](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/)

- https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2018/05/03/exporting-data-from-pdfs-with-python/
- https://dzone.com/articles/exporting-data-from-pdfs-with-python

PS:

`os.startfile()` is causing "file in use", hence preventing `os.rename()`.  Perhaps you can just move/rename the file *FIRST*?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, very useful. Unfortunately I can't rename the file first because the new name is dependent on some data that are in the file, so I need to open the PDF, read it and only at this moment I have all the informations that I need to rename the file properly.

Comment: So it sounds like 1) You truly need to "read" the .pdf, and 2) "os.startfile()" is *NOT* the appropriate tool for the job. And yes, there *ARE* "smarter ways to do it" ;)  Q: Have you tried [PDFMiner](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/) yet?  Q: Are there any problems doing so?

Comment: No, I haven't tried with PDFMiner yet; the PDFs are very different one from another, so I don't think that is gonna be a trivial task, in addition to that I am completely new to that library, but I will try for sure.

Comment: That's exactly why you want to use a library: to simplify dealing with the files' variance ;)  Read the two links I cited to help you "get started".  Good luck!  And please feel free to "upvote" and/or "accept".